# Considering nontrivial $\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf P$

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization, dipole-moment

For the following image:

[image]

I am told that this solid cylinder is essentially a bar electret, which has a uniformly distributed $\mathbf P$ throughout its volume. There are no free charges, I will posit.

Apparently, the curl of $\mathbf P$ is azimuthal. Why is there even a non-zero curl in the first place? How can this be reasoned?

The exercise's prompt:

> A solid   cylinder    has a   permanent   polarization    $\mathbf P$ distributed
>   uniformly  throughout  its     volume,
>   directed  as  shown   in  the diagram at  right. The   cylinder    is 
>   surrounded     by  empty   space,  and     there  are  no  other   charges     or 
>   fields    anywhere     except  those that  might   be  due     to  the
>   polarization  of  this    material    object.

Here is the exact question I’m trying to answer. It is (e).

[image]

Comment: When you say that $P$ is uniformly distributed throughout the volume, do you mean that it is uniform throughout the volume, or that it changes uniformly throughout the volume in some way? In other words, if I were to look at the bound charge density, would I see two surfaces of charge, one positive at the top, one negative at the bottom? Or would I see some sort of linear gradient where the charge density gets steadily more and more negative towards the bottom and steadily more positive towards the top? (Neither of these is curly but maybe the charge changes over the cross section too?)

Comment: @CRDrost The former.

Comment: I mean, then you have a uniform field, all uniform fields have curl zero and divergence zero trivially by virtue of all their partial derivatives being zero.

Comment: @CRDrost That's my thinking, but the feedback notes it as having azimuthal curl. I'll attach the question prompt for the exercise.

Comment: Where in the problem statement does it ask for $\nabla \times P$?

Comment: I think you mean that P is the curl of some field that is azimuthal within the cylinder.

Comment: The problem specifically asks where the curl of the electric displacement is non-zero, which is apparently on the curved part of the cylinder. I asked for the curl of the polarization in my question, which may have been a mistake, but since this only contains bound charge they should be equivalent.

Comment: I haven’t shown the text for the question itself but I will attach it now.

Comment: The answer recommends placing a pinwheel on the left curved side of the surface and noting that the right side of it will be in the volume where P exists, which will start the wheel to rotate.

Comment: At the curved surfaces of the cylinder, P changes abruptly from P to zero, so it is not uniform there, and does have a curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curl of the polarization is a tricky beast to consider in this situation, because $\mathbf P$ is a discontinuous function, and you need to tread very carefully with its derivatives.

To deal effectively with $\nabla\times\mathbf P$ for this problem, the easiest route is to do two things:

- Use the cylindrical-coordinates version of the curl,
  \begin{align}
  \nabla \times \mathbf P
  & =
  \left({\frac {1}{\rho }}{\frac {\partial P_{z}}{\partial \varphi }}-{\frac {\partial P_{\varphi }}{\partial z}}\right) {\hat {\boldsymbol {\rho }}}
  +\left({\frac {\partial P_{\rho }}{\partial z}}-{\frac {\partial P_{z}}{\partial \rho }}\right){\hat {\boldsymbol {\varphi }}}
  +{\frac {1}{\rho }}\left({\frac {\partial \left(\rho P_{\varphi }\right)}{\partial \rho }}-{\frac {\partial P_{\rho }}{\partial \varphi }}\right){\hat {\mathbf {z} }}
  \end{align}
- Swap the discontinuous shift from nonzero-to-zero $P_z$ to a smooth tail-down at both the end-caps and the cylindrical surface, and work qualitatively (if you need to).

If you do things correctly, the first step should be enough - just knowing that $\mathbf P$ is directed exclusively along $z$, and that it has rotational symmetry about the axis, should be sufficient to ascertain the direction of $\nabla\times \mathbf P$.

If you want to calculate $\nabla\times\mathbf P$ exactly, though, for the discontinuous polarization distribution, then you will be faced with calculating $\partial P_z/\partial \rho$ where $P_z = P_z(\rho)$ is a Heaviside theta function, whose derivative has [some interesting properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/how-to-prove-that-the-derivative-of-heavisides-unit-step-function-is-the-dirac).